# Set log-warnings=2 in mysqld but not getting user login detail in log file

Tags: mysql, logging, redhat

I'm trying to get more detail in the log file specifically to see failed user authentications against my databases.

Running RedHat 6.5
MySQL 5.1.71

In file /etc/my.cnf I added the log-warnings=2

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0
skip-name-resolve

[mysqld_safe]
log-warnings=2
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

-Peter

Answer (score 1):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19285/log-warnings-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-aborted-connections-in-mysql-5-1

Known bug i believe.
probably fix in 6.0 is what it says....